Does the horizon mark a geometrical intersection of some sort between the earth and the sky?
The earth is more or less a sphere unto itself. The sky is, say, everything else. The horizon border separates the earth from the sky. But can it be said that there is a geometrical intersection of some sort being marked – or would this be considered a mere case of bordering forms?

In a simplified model, the horizon can be viewed as the intersection of the Celestial Sphere, which is in some sense a mathematical representation of "the sky", and the plane of tangency to the spherical surface of the earth at the point where you're standing.
Anything above the horizon represents a line of sight that points away from earth; anything below the horizon represents a line of sight that intersects the earth. Anything at the horizon, you're precisely skimming the surface.
(This is of course abstracting away tons of details, but it's a good first approach.)
